# How to create permanent aliases on Unix-like systems?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc, multiuser

I am looking for a simple way to create a permanent alias for all users. So `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` is not an option.

Hasn't anybody created a program for this? I think it should be a very common need. If not, I can always create a custom [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script, but I need to know if there is a equivalent of .bash_profile for all users.

In my case, I am using Mac OS X v10.9 (Mavericks) and Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), but I would like a method that works on major Unix systems.

**UPDATE:** I was wondering about a program which automatically allows the users to manage a list of permanent of aliases directly from the command-line without having to edit files. It would have options for setting for all users, target users, interative/login shell, etc.

**UPDATE 2:** Reply to answer of @jimmij

```
$ su -m
Password:
# cat /etc/profile
alias test343="echo working"
# cat /etc/bash.bashrc
alias test727="echo working"
# test727
bash: test727: command not found
# test343
bash: test343: command not found
```

Comment: First you are talking about files then about a program...

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm talking about possible solutions for my problem. I'll edit to clarify this

Comment: @NeDark was that test on OSX or on Ubuntu?

Comment: Re: Update #2. Exit the shell and try again.

Comment: @cremefraiche I did restart shell, anyway it only happens using `-m`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please have a look at `bash` manual:

- **/etc/profile**

  The systemwide initialization file, executed for interactive login shells
- **/etc/bash.bashrc**

  The systemwide initialization file, executed for interactive, non-login shells.
- **~/.bash_profile**

  The personal initialization file, executed for interactive login shells
- **~/.bashrc**

  The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
- **~/.bash_logout**

  The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits

So you need to put your aliases in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` in order to make them available for all users.

Comment: @terdon where did you get this `/etc/bash.bashrc` from? My manual of `GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)` doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: I've always known about it as the global init file, it's been around for as long as I've been using bash. It is also mentioned in the man page for my `bash 4.3.25`. That's where you define global stuff for interactive, non-login shells. Are you saying that `man bash | grep -F bash.bashrc` returns nothing on your system?

Comment: @terdon that is correct, I'm right now in front of recent *stable* bash on gentoo box, but there are indeed more recent unstable versions up to `4.3.33`

Comment: @terdon At least on OS X yes, version 3.2.51(1)

Comment: @jimmij Ubuntu 10.04's bash (4.1.something) does use it. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/bash.1.html. Also [Debian 6's](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en)

Comment: Not working, details in question

Comment: @NeDark Did you tried to with `su -`? `su -m` preserves environment, it is possible that it doesn't parse rc files.

Comment: @jimmij Ok, that was the problem :) Working now thanks

Comment: I checked the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) and found no mention of it! Still, I have been using it for years, it has been present on all systems I've ever used and it _is_ mentioned in my `man bash`. Something like that is needed though since non-login shells will not read `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.profile`.

Comment: Additionally, you may substitute aliases with commands (executables) which could be written as shell scripts: `/usr/local/bin/test727` would contain `#!/usr/bin/bash\n echo "working";`. This way, all users will have access to that command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ruby installed, you can use [aka](http://github.com/ytbryan/aka) to generate permanent alias on the fly.